# Including HTML in Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have written this code here in the controller when an admin wants to delete a drug:

```
 $msg = 'You are not authorized to delete this drug the drug belongs to ,<a href="'. action('UserController@viewStore',$drug->drugStore->id) . '"> {{$drug->drugStore->name}}</a>';
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', $msg);
```

In the other Blade file I have this session alert:

```
@if(session()->has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>Wrong!</strong> {!!session('error')!!}.
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
    </div>
@endif
```

The href is being successfully created but I am trying to add `{{$drug->drugStore->name}}` but is keep taking it as a plain text.

The alert that is being shown:

> **Wrong! You are not authorized to delete this drug the drug belongs to , {{$drug->drugStore->name}}.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{ $var }}` syntax is only for use in Blade files.

In your controller, you should be using standard PHP concatenation:

```
$msg = 'You .... to <a href="'. action('UserController@viewStore', $drug->drugStore->id) . '">' . $drug->drugStore->name . '</a>';
//                                                                                            ^^^^                      ^^^^
```